# How to fix BCrypt-3.1.11 hashed passwords appended stream of "\x00" characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, bcrypt

I recently started getting BCrypt "invalid hash" errors when I tried to save a record with a password, so I looked into the BCrypt code, and found the following method for validating passwords:

```
  def valid_hash?(h)
    h =~ /^\$[0-9a-z]{2}\$[0-9]{2}\$[A-Za-z0-9\.\/]{53}$/
  end
```

which is called by the `initialize` method:

```
def initialize(raw_hash)
  if valid_hash?(raw_hash)
    self.replace(raw_hash)
    @version, @cost, @salt, @checksum = split_hash(self)
  else
    raise Errors::InvalidHash.new("invalid hash")
  end
end
```

The following passwords:

```
"PassiveForbearenceFox"
"VindictivePurpleAlligator12345"
"LostBlueLizard!@#$1234"
```

all return "Invalid Hash" errors.

I dug deeper, and found that the regex is checking the hashed password, but the hash that is getting passed has a stream of `/x00`s after it.

For example, if I use the password "LostBlueLizard!@#1234", the hash that is passed to challenge the regex is:

```
"$2a$11$NcmldbbyCDfumGYALgYhfuIQt2FZ8gpbVCQfuiVlwjhCtkD2ndDFy\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\...
```

and so on, for farther than I could scroll.

If I remove the `\x00`s and pass in `$2a$11$NcmldbbyCDfumGYALgYhfuIQt2FZ8gpbVCQfuiVlwjhCtkD2ndDFy`, it passes the regex.

Why does the hash have those characters? I can't prove they weren't there before, but my passwords were always accepted until recently.

---

Also, it's actually the `raw_hash` that's getting input into the `initialize` method that's the hash with all the `\x00`s. So somewhere there's code that generates the faulty hash and passes it to `initialize`, but I searched the entire gem's codebase for the term "initialize" and there were no results like that, so I can't find where the hash is actually generated.

---

I tracked the issue further, to the `BCrypt::Engine.create` method, which calls `__bc_crypt`, which is what returns the faulty hash. `__bc_crypt` is actually from the C source file `ext/mri/bcrypt_ext.c`, which is beyond my ability to investigate.

I updated BCrypt from 3.1.11 to 3.1.13, and now it works fine. I'm not sure whether it was a bug or not, but the point is it works now.

Comment: Has to be 60 chars onloy. Dollar + 2 alnum + Dollar + 2 num + Dollar + 53 alnum or dot or forward slish.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a regex question

Comment: @theTinMan I don't care one way or the other, but couldn't it be useful to someone using BCrypt 3.1.11?

Comment: Technically, problems we can't reproduce or that are the result of a bug are considered off-topic, but, because it wasn't actually in your code, it might have redeeming value for the site. I'm not going to flag the question to be closed, but, others in the community might. I'll delete my previous comment, and we'll let the ecosystem/nature take its course.

Comment: Please note the changes I made to the question. Using "edit" or "update" tags when modifying your text is undesirable. Instead, as you make changes, incorporate them as if they'd been part of the text all along, to preserve readability. SO maintains revision tracking for question and answers, and once you have a certain level of points in the community you can see those changes, making the tags superfluous, but worse, they're distracting. As a result they get edited out.

Comment: @theTinMan Duly noted, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -3):

It does not mean the Bcrypt's valid_hash? method is wrong, it means that the password stored, that one is invalid or nil which does not match the valid hash system

you may have to add

```
has_secure_password
```

if that one is not there and check the password_digest field after that.